# Grouping records using LINQ method syntax

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I'm trying to find a way to group records by date (not taking into account time) using the LINQ method syntax but only select one instance of each record (which is ItemId within the model)

My simple query is as follows:

```
range1.Count(x => ((x.OpenedDate >= todayFirst) && (x.OpenedDate <= todayLast))
```

How could I count the unique records within this range by `ItemId`?

Comment: Please stop tagging questions that have nothing to do with ASP.NET MVC with the `asp.net-mvc` tag.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like you want:

```
var query = range1.Where(x.OpenedDate >= todayFirst && x.OpenedDate <= todayLast)
                  .GroupBy(x => x.ItemId)
                  .Select(g => new { ItemId = g.Key, Count = g.Count() });

foreach (var result in query)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0} - {1}", result.ItemId, result.Count);
}
```

It's possible that I haven't really understood you properly though - it's not clear whether you really want to group by date or item ID

EDIT: If you just want the count of distinct item IDs in that range, you can use:

```
var count = range1.Where(x.OpenedDate >= todayFirst && x.OpenedDate <= todayLast)
                  .Select(x => x.ItemId)
                  .Distinct()
                  .Count();
```

Comment: Thanks Jon. How do I access the integer 'count' value of the query? I'm looking for the quantity of all records between the todayFirst and todayLast date with unique ItemId values.

Comment: @Nick: I've edited the answer to show iterating over the results.

Comment: @Nick: Okay, I think I'd misunderstood the question - just using `query.Count()` will give you the answer to that, but there's a simpler way... edited it in.